# Is it possible for a function to call another function in another function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I want to create multiple function apps, but I'd like to know if it's possible for one function in one app to call another function in another app. I can't find any documentation on this. I looked at durable functions, but it appears the functions can talk to each other if they belong to the same [task hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp) (i.e. same app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durable Functions won't work like this because the orchestrator needs to know about the other Functions, but there's no reason you can't trigger a function in another function app. Just invoke its trigger.

Comment: Thanks. Can I only invoke HttpTriggers in other apps? What about other types of functions?

Comment: You can use literally anything you want. Try it and see.